# How to get part description for catalogentryID

Tags: websphere-commerce, wcs

I am using IBM WCS 7 aurorab2b store.

I want to retrieve the description of a `partNumber` entered by user. I am getting `catentryID` = *14726* and `langId` as *-1*. I tried the following way and I am getting `javax.ejb.DuplicateKeyException` when creating instance of `CatalogEntryDescriptionAccessBean`

```
try{

    String catentID = catlogBean.getCatalogEntryReferenceNumber();
    long catentryID = Long.parseLong(catentID);
    Integer langID = Integer.parseInt(getLanguageId());
    System.out.println("catEntryID:"+catentryID);
    System.out.println("langID:"+langID+"");
    CatalogEntryDescriptionAccessBean catlogDescriptionBean = new CatalogEntryDescriptionAccessBean(catentryID,langID);

    if(catlogDescriptionBean == null)
        System.out.println("catlogDescriptionBean is null");
    else
        System.out.println("catlogDescriptionBean is not null");

    description = catlogDescriptionBean.getShortDescription();
}
catch(Exception e){
    System.out.println("EXCEPTION IN DESCRPTN");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note calling the constructor of access bean will Maps to a corresponding ejbCreate method in the home interface of the EJB. which means you are creating new record which already exist.

use the following way to get description using access beans:

```
CatalogEntryAccessBean catEntryAB = new CatalogEntryAccessBean();
catEntryAB.setInitKey_catalogEntryReferenceNumber(catentry_id);

catEntryAB.refreshCopyHelper();

CatalogEntryDescriptionAccessBean catEntryDescAB = catEntryAB.getDescription(langId);
```

you need yo catch suitable exceptions thrown by bean EJBs and get the description from catEntryDescAB object.

Update : 2nd way to achieve same :

```
String longDesc = CatalogEntryCache.getDescription(catEntryAB , 
                        this.commandContext.getLanguageId(), getStoreId()).getLongDescription()
```

please note in JSPs , WCS is using Solr to get production information , please read ProductDisplay.jsp to see the wcf services used and corresponding access/search profiles.

hope that answers your question.

Thanks

Abed

Comment: thanks for replying! I am getting instance of CatalogEntryAccessBean by iterating enumeration  returned by findByPartNumbersAndStore(java.lang.String[] partNumbers, java.lang.Integer storeId) , So after getting the instance of CatalogEntryAccessBean & i can get catentryID by getCatalogEntryReferenceNumber. so now again I have to do catEntryAB.setInitKey_catalogEntryReferenceNumber(catentry_id); ???  catentId is already present is it require to pass again before

Comment: No , if you have the access bean ready from previous operations , then you can used it with calling setInitKey_catalogEntryReferenceNumber(catentry_id) again .

Comment: CatalogEntryAccessBean catalogAccessBean = new CatalogEntryAccessBean();
 
   Enumeration enumeration = catalogAccessBean.findByPartNumbersAndStore(partNumberArray, getStoreId());
   while(enumeration.hasMoreElements()){
    CatalogEntryAccessBean  catlogBean = (CatalogEntryAccessBean)enumeration.nextElement();
    
    CatalogEntryDescriptionAccessBean catlogDescriptionBean =   catlogBean.getDescription();

Comment: For catlogBean.getDescription();   m getting duplicate exception

Comment: use getDescription(langId); . i need to look at exception stacktrace

Comment: getDescription takes Integer langId and Throws:
NamingException
FinderException
CreateException
RemoteException , check your code and fix your number format exception . i've done that many times and it is working for me

Comment: Rad will give warning sign for these 4 exception for ejb that I handled, the exception is different from all these thatsy I put the question

Comment: just updated my answer above , try 2nd way to do this 
    String longDesc = CatalogEntryCache.getDescription(catEntryAB , 
          this.commandContext.getLanguageId(), getStoreId()).getLongDescription() . please note both are working with me . if this did not work for you . then you have something else in you application

Comment: Thanks @Abed finally both ways are   working, second way is the better way as it reduce no. of statements,